# How can I listen for the end of a build using VSTS WebApi?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm building as part of a larger process that analyzes the results of the build once it has completed. I used to work with XAML builds via C# code, and I had the following code:

```
 QueuedBuild.Connect();
 QueuedBuild.PollingCompleted += PrivateServerBuildRequest.BuildCompleted;
```

(`QueuedBuild` was `IQueuedBuild` type),

With new WebApi builds, do I have an event that let me know that the build has completed?

I found `BuildCompletedEvent` in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Events` but I didn't manage to find the way to use it.

Is there any equivalent to  `PollingCompleted` event in WebApi builds? Something that'll fire once all build results are available?

Comment: What is your specific goal here? What activity do you want to happen when the build completes? There is likely going to be a better way of accomplishing it. The short answer to your current question is "No". The new build system does not work the same way or use the same APIs.

Comment: @DanielMann I know it's not the same, I want an event that will occur when the build is complete, I asked if there is an equivalent in the new API

Comment: There isn't, which is why I asked *specifically* what your goal was.

Comment: @DanielMann why is: 'an event that will occur when the build is complete' not specific enough? a way to know a build has completed without the need to pull the answer by myself

Comment: Because if you explain what your goal is, I can make suggestions on how to accomplish it using tools that are available. You can't do the thing you want to do. The next step is finding an alternate method. I can help you with that, but I need to understand your end goal to do so.

Comment: @DanielMann I need to be able to continue the flow once I triggered the build, than when it's over, get notified and use the result data of the build  (all build information) in order to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible alternatives with the new REST API is to use [Service Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/overview?view=vsts). In particular, you might want to pay attention to the generic [Web Hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts), whcih can basically instruct VSTS to POST some JSON payload (once a certain event occurs) to some endpoint.

The endpoint can be anything: your custom home-made service hosted on-prem, OR an Azure Function, for instance. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fintegrate%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Fintegrate%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts#configure-a-service-hook-for-pr-events) can give you an idea how to trigger an Azure Function in response to a VSTS event.

The '[Build Completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/events?toc=/vsts/integrate/toc.json&bc=/vsts/integrate/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts#build.complete)' event is in the [list of available events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/events?toc=/vsts/integrate/toc.json&bc=/vsts/integrate/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts).

So, to sum it all up, I would try the following in your case:

- Create an Azure Function to accept the build info payload and process it accordingly
- Subscribe to Build Completed event with the Web Hook and make sure the Azure Function URL is used as the endpoint